# Naming conventions in AutoMapper when unflattening foreign key

Tags: c#, automapper

I've just started looking at AutoMapper and wish to change one specific behaviour.

I have a simple view model that contains a foreign key which I want to convert using a custom converter. My problem however is that I cannot get it to work unless I name the property in the view model the same as the type name.

The following code works correctly, but I would rather name the Guid in DeviceTemperatureEntryViewModel DeviceId instead of only Device. If I name it DeviceId the unflattening works, resulting in a Device type with the Id set correctly, but the custom converter is not invoked.

```
public MappingProfile()
{

    CreateMap<Device, DeviceViewModel>().ReverseMap();
    CreateMap<DeviceTemperatureEntry, DeviceTemperatureEntryViewModel>().ReverseMap();

    // Lookups
    CreateMap<Guid, Device>().ConvertUsing<EntityConverter<Device>>();
}

public class EntityConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<Guid, T> where T : class
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public EntityConverter(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public T Convert(Guid source, T destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _context.Find<T>(source);// default(T);
    }
}

public class DeviceTemperatureEntryViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Device { get; set; }
    public double Temperature { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceTemperatureEntry : DeviceEntry
{
    public double Temperature { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceEntry
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public Device Device { get; set; }

    public DeviceEntry()
    {
        Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide between unflatening and a map from Guid to Device.

Comment: Are you saying that by calling the property DeviceId i'm implicitly selecting unflattening since that matches Device.Id? Otherwise it checks the source and destination types?

Comment: Yes. I don't know of a simple way to disable the default naming convention, but see [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/922).

Comment: AddMemberConfiguration()    .AddMember<NameSplitMember>()    .AddName<PrePostfixName>(name => name.AddStrings(p => p.Postfixes, "Id")); worked, but it also updated the Id property unfortunately :(

Comment: I have no idea what that does, but if you really what to disable the naming convention, do what that PR does.